# Android MediaPlayer to play video stream in Service screen rotation

Tags: android, android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-service-binding

I would like to create Activity with video player to play online stream using MediaPlayer class and SurfaceView to display. I'm creating MediaPlayer in separate Service so after screen rotation player don't have to be created again and don't have to connect to stream. My problem is that I don't know how to write Activity so my service wouldn't start every time after screen rotation.

My code below, in onStart() I start service but I don't know how to change it so it didn't start every time.

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private String path;
    private SurfaceHolder vidHolder;
    private SurfaceView vidSurface;
    private VideoService videoService;
    private Intent playIntent;
    private boolean videoBound = false;

    private ServiceConnection musicConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            VideoService.VideoBinder binder = (VideoService.VideoBinder) service;
            videoService = binder.getService();
            videoService.setUrl(path);
            videoBound = true;
            if (vidHolder != null && videoService.getMediaPlayer() != null) {
                videoService.getMediaPlayer().setDisplay(vidHolder);
                videoService.playVideo();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            videoBound = false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        path = "https://archive.org/download/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet/ksnn_compilation_master_the_internet_512kb.mp4"; //TODO tmp
        playIntent = new Intent(this, VideoService.class);
        bindService(playIntent, musicConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        startService(playIntent);
        vidSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfView);
        vidHolder = vidSurface.getHolder();
        vidHolder.addCallback(VideoPlayerActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        if (videoService != null && videoService.getMediaPlayer() != null) {
            videoService.getMediaPlayer().setDisplay(vidHolder);
        } 
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        Log.d("ServiceConnection", "surfaceChanged  " + i + "   " + i1 + "   " + i2);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        Log.d("ServiceConnection", "surfaceDestroyed");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unbindService(musicConnection);
        stopService(playIntent);
        videoService = null;
    }
}
```

Service class:

```
public class VideoService extends Service implements OnPreparedListener {
    private MediaPlayer player;
    private String path;
    private final IBinder musicBind = new VideoBinder();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("VideoService", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate();
        player = new MediaPlayer();
        initMusicPlayer();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return musicBind;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent){
        player.stop();
        player.release();
        return false;
    }

    public void initMusicPlayer() {
        player.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    }

    public void playVideo() {
        try {
            player.setDataSource(path);
            player.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        path = url;
    }

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public class VideoBinder extends Binder {
        public VideoService getService() {
            return VideoService.this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem with starting your service multiple times?

Comment: @pskink Every time MediaPlayer is created and it have to connect to stream (it takes few seconds)

Comment: you are creating MediaPlayer in `onCreate`, that method is  called only once, not every time `startService` is called, more [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics)

Comment: also, if you are calling `unbindService` in `onDestroy` you should call `bindService` in `onCreate`, not in `onStart`

Comment: @pskink I moved bindService to onCreate and added logging on service onCreate and after screen rotation service onCreate is called every time.

Comment: dont call `stopService(playIntent);`

Comment: @pskink ok, now onCreate is not called but I get exception java.lang.IllegalStateException (without any message) on line videoService.getMediaPlayer().setDisplay(vidHolder); inside ServiceConnection. Any idea?

Comment: is `vidHolder` a valid SurfaceHolder? tried to log it?

Comment: @pskink vidHolder is not null if that's what you're asking

Comment: what is full exception stack trace like?

Comment: @pskink I just added android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" to manifest and now it's working without any exception!

Comment: @user3626048 Then why is my answer downvoted and not accepted!? It gives you exactly that as one of the two options.

Comment: @alf I didn't downvote your answer, someone else must have done it. Your answer helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either check for `savedInstanceState` being null to only start the service if the Activity is freshly created

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        startService...
}
```

or handle screen rotation yourself by adding

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

to your Activity in manifest. Like this onCreate will not be called on rotation any more.